# How can I get yum to recommend packages based on my stupidity?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I used to use Ubuntu (apt-get) and I feel like if I would say `apt-get install this_packge` and there was a package named `this_package`, that it would recognize the mistake and say something like:

```
...
"this_packge" is unavailable
did you mean "this_package"?
...
```

or something similar. However, when I am asking `yum` to find things (for example, `gmp-dev`, and I should actually be searching for `gmp-devel`) it doesn't give me any recommendations on what I am actually looking for. Is there a way to get yum to recommend similarly titled packages to one that I list?

Comment: IMHO unfortunately no :(

Comment: You can;t, but you can use wildcard in: yum search gmp*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commands that can give you the actual package name like

- yum search
- You can use rpm -qa package name
- you can use yum list
- You can add repository to get additional third party packages

If package is not found by yum then it means it is not available in yum repository. So you can add new repository to get it available in yum repository.
You have to add .repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory with proper address and gpk keys.

I hope this would help.